# how to solve MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured in wamp server

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Please help me , I am tried all the things that I have found in my the search.
Like changing in `config.inc.php` and `my.ini` etc.

Please tell me what can I change to solve the following error

> #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured problem.

my config.inc.php file is

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Only Change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';` insted of `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';`

Comment: Could you provide some more information, such as the setting in config.inc.php (remember to mask out the password), where does your MySQL server runs with respect to your Apache server (are they on the same machine or different?), whether you can use telnet on the machine running Apache to mysql server, etc?

Comment: my config.inc.php file is 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;                                                     Only Change  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';  insted of  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';

Comment: Did you try to run the command `telnet localhost 3306`, does it successfully connect to the MySQL server?

Also, did you successfully connect to the MySQL server with MySQL client?

Comment: No, but when I am tested this gives on command prompt                              N
 5.5.16-log♥X4<n8j.☻Ç§M6dwIE_.f;1"mysql_native_password                     after some time print bellow message.

Connection to host lost.

C:\Documents and Settings\Ganesh>

Comment: Did you try to specify the port number, 3306, in the config above?

Comment: Yes, but gives the same error                                                                    #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Comment: Did you try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: No, Ok ,now I am trying........                                              I have tried but getting same error.